# sending image as base64 within http post

Tags: node.js, http, post, base64

I have been trying to upload my image as a base64 string to amazon s3 but the base64 string within my s3 bucket is corrupted. Is there anything wrong with the configuration of my HTTP POST, such as the content-type specified?

```
var image = webcamImage.imageAsBase64;

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
  })
};


this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8888/upload", image, httpOptions).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `ContentEncoding` to `'base64'` and `ContentType` to `'image/jpeg'`.